# Differences in Hosting WCF services vs Web API - Startup

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api2

My organization is transitioning from MS WCF services to Web API services. One big difference I've noticed is in the startup behavior. If a WCF service isn't spun up, it waits to return until it is spun up. However, if a Web API service is not spun up, it returns 500s until it is spun up.

Is there any way to configure the Web API applications or IIS so that it starts up more like a WCF service, in that it doesn't return anything until it's spun up? I've googled extensively but have been unable to find anything addressing this.

As an FYI, app init isn't an option for us right now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is configurable via IIS.

See here:

[Auto-Start Feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260(v=azure.10).aspx)

Comment: This link is related to App Fabric, unfortunately.